# Долгий запрос между серверами

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер, sphinxsearch

Ситуация такая, есть сайт, она находится на обычном хостинге (сервер 1)
Я купил впс (сервер 2), чтобы разобраться с поиском через sphinx, настроил, делаю поиск на этом сервере - результат приходит мгновенно, максимум 50-100 мс, на отдачу страницы в браузер.

Ну и я что придумал, буду отдавать запрос на 2й сервер (curl или клиентом phpsphinx), и забирать результат, и выдавать в браузер. тоесть как бы работа 2го сервера остается в фоне невидимая.

Но столкнулся с дикими задержками, первый запрос жду несколько секунд (доходит до 5-10 секунд), но если потом обновлю тот же результат, страница отдается быстро. но ввожу другой запрос, снова жду долго...

вобщем что за проблема???

UPD:
дело точно не в запросе, проверил на чистом php скрипте все быстро...

UPD:
все решилось. дело было в автокомплите при поиске, когда я набирал поисковой текст, делалось множество запросов на сайт и затормаживало основной запрос формы, отключил jquery.autocomlete все залетало

Comment: ping с 1 на 2 сервер какой.

Comment: все решилось, обновил пост